# how to count number of execution of specific row in MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I write a python script that need to count log in to web page.
I have many user names and passwords , and I want to count how many times every username used to login,
at the first I count the number of calling method login() but it not answer me!
because the count value for all table rows will updated,
here is my code:

```
counter = 0

def user_pass():  # send username & password for login method
    global counter
    counter += 1
    curser.execute("SELECT username,password,use_num FROM users ORDER BY RAND()")
    users = curser.fetchone()
    _user = users[0]
    _pass = users[1]
    _usenum = users[2]
    print(_user, _pass, _usenum)
    if int(_usenum) < 3:
        z = int(_usenum)
        z += 1    # to avoid use more than 3 times of one user&pass
        quer = "UPDATE users SET use_num = %s "
        curser.execute(quer, [z])
        myConnection.commit()

        return _user, _pass
    else:
        if counter > 4:
            print("most of user&pass rich limit take an action")
        else:
            user_pass()
```

I tried to count number of call method login() but not give me right answer

Answer (score 0):

in line

```
 quer = "UPDATE users SET use_num = %s "
```

just need to WHERE in the end of query like this:

```
counter = 0
def user_pass():  # send username & password for login method
    global counter
    counter += 1
    curser.execute("SELECT id,username,password,use_num FROM users ORDER BY RAND()")
    users = curser.fetchone()
    _id = users[0]
    _user = users[1]
    _pass = users[2]
    _usenum = users[3]
    print(_user, _pass, _usenum)
    if int(_usenum) < 3:
       z = int(_usenum)
       z += 1    # to avoid use more than 3 times of one user&pass
       quer = f"UPDATE users SET use_num = %s WHERE id = {_id}"
       curser.execute(quer, [z])
       myConnection.commit()

       return _user, _pass
   else:
       if counter > 4:
           print("most of user&pass rich limit take an action")
   else:
        user_pass()
```